# checking for a name inside an object

Tags: python, class

Struggling to figure out how to check that a name, given as an argument, exists within a larger name. Have tried with .split() but only get assertionerror all the time.

```
def __init__(self, artist, title):
         self._artist = artist
     self._title = title

def check_artist(self, name):
         if name in self._artist:
             return True
         else:
             return False

     song1 = Song("Lady Gaga and Bradley Cooper", "Shallow")

     print("Testing check_artist with 'Lady Gaga and Bradley Cooper'") # True
     assert(song1.check_artist("Lady Gaga and Bradley Cooper"))
     print("Testing check_artist with 'Lord Gaga'") # True, one word exists in the artist name
     assert(song1.check_artist("Lord Gaga"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation on [assert](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement), `assert` as you are using it is basically equivalent to:

```
if not <expression>: raise AssertionError
```

Your code is actually functioning as expected, as "Lord Gaga" is not in the artist name. A better use of `assert` here would be:

```
assert not song1.check_artist("Lord Gaga")
assert song1.check_artist("Lady Gaga")
```

which will correctly verify the functionality of your method (parenthesis aren't necessary).